# How to get a list of bundled products using wp_query in woocommerce

Tags: plugins, wp-query, loop, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to fetch a list of bundled products using WP_Query.I have used the following

```
   $args = array( 
            'post_type' => 'product',               
            'posts_per_page' => 9, 
            'orderby' =>'date',
            'orderby' => 'rand', 
            'meta_query'=>array(
                array(
                    'key'=>'_thumbnail_id', 

                )
            )
        );

 $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

How can i pass an argument to get bundled products? Can anyone help please..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do it using 'tax_query':

```
'tax_query'=> array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_type',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'bundle', 
    ),
),
```

Comment: Thanks mate! already fixed,forgot to update it here.Anyway this was the correct answer.